# What is this component marked "ZW1" on a LED doorbell button PCB?

Tags: identification

It's packaged in glass, like a diode.  The PCB is out of a lighted doorbell button.  The silk screened moniker is "ZW1".  Google and my Electronics Dictionary fail me.  Can you please suggest a generic type for this guy, e.g. diode, resistor, etc.?

[image: LED doorbell button PCB]

Answer (score 3):

Its a zener diode. It will have a voltage rating which may be marked on the diode body.